# Using onEdit(e) to update cells when new value is added

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

A piece of code I am working on consists of two functions - `generateID` and `onEdit(e)`.
`generateID` - generates a number using pattern and it works fine.
`onEdit(e)` is the one I am having issue with.

In **column A** of a spreadsheet, a user selects a value from a dropdown (initially **column A** is empty, range is from row `2` to `getLastRow()`, row 1 for heading).
Once the value is selected, I need the result of the `generateID` to be inserted into the next **column B** of the same row.
If a value in **coumn A** is then changed (selected from dropdown), I need `generateID` to update its value.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = ss.getSheetByName("TEMP");
  var range = activeSheet.getRange(2, 1, activeSheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues(); 

  for (var i =0; i < range.length; i ++) {
    if (e.range [i][0] !== "") {
       activeSheet.getRange(i + 2, 2, 1, 1).setValue(generateID());
    };
  };
};
```

onEdit seems to be the right choice to watch changes in the range. With (e) the code seems not to work at all. Trying it as `onEdit()` works but incorrectly.
Apprecaite any help on this.
Thank you.

Comment: Your issue is probably in the line (e.range [i][0] !== "") A range is not an array. Try e.range.getValues()[i][0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.range` returns a `range` object and not a array[<sup>1</sup>](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit). Try this instead of your code:

```
e.value !=='' ? e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(generateID()) : null
```